# Upload file into S3 with AWS SDK ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image from ASP.NET to S3. I am using AWS SDK for that and have already set up what is needed. However, after i run my project, i received an error. I'll be replacing my bucket name to ... for this sample code.

I set up my secretkey and accesskey from User in my Web.config. Please do tell me if u need more codes. I need help.

controller

```
private static readonly string _awsAccessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];

private static readonly string _awsSecretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"];

[HttpPost]  
        public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
        {
            try  
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    IAmazonS3 client;
                    using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey))
                    {
                        PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
                        {
                            BucketName = "...",
                            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                            Key = "images/" + (DateTime.Now.ToBinary() + "-" + file.FileName),
                            FilePath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles")
                        };

                        client.PutObject(request);
                    }


                }

                imageUrls = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File Uploaded Successfully!!");

                return Json(imageUrls);
            }  
            catch  
            {  
                ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("File upload failed!!");
                return Json(ViewBag.Message);  
            }  
        }
```

Comment: What's the error you're receiving?

Comment: @KhalidT. An unhandled exception has occurred. Exception type: HttpException

    Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. I realized i did not place region in AWSClientFactory, right at the end after the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error due to `DateTime.Now.ToBinary()` which contains invalid characters to be used in a URL. For example, you could use a GUID or a Unix timestamp instead.

Also, the `FilePath` property you're assigning to the `PutObjectRequest` is the full path and name to a file to be uploaded. So, you don't need it when you already have `HttpPostedFileBase` as an input parameter, which contains the `InputStream` property (i.e., the stream object).

Your `PutObjectRequest` should look something like this:

```
.
.
.
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

// Create a client
AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey);

// Create a PutObject request
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = "...",
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
    Key = "images/" + guid + "-" + file.FileName
};

using (System.IO.Stream inputStream = file.InputStream)
{
    request.InputStream = inputStream;

    // Put object
    PutObjectResponse response = client.PutObject(request);
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: i have error on file.InputStream. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.IO.FileStream'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?

Comment: I change to stream instead of filestream due to the error. Run it and it still failed

Comment: Please see my updated answer for the Unix timestamp and file.InputStream

Comment: Nope, it still failed

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Your target framework might be 4.5, which does not support `ToUnixTimeSeconds()` as in 4.6. Maybe it is better to use a GUID as shown in the updated code above. I already have tested it on 4.5 and it works. Also, maybe you're missing the AWS region endpoint for the client.

Comment: same error as the one above. I removed the datetime and tried to run it, it still give me the same http error.

Comment: Other things to try: Check the posted file name if it contains invalid characters.

Comment: filename most _ , - and full-stop. Im not sure why it is still not working

Comment: The error explicitly says there is a (<) character in the path. You might want to double check the bucket name, file name and/or other areas in your code.

Comment: i went to see and apparently it didnt went in using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey)). I not sure if this will be the possible cause.

Comment: i finally solved it! I did not place region in AWSClientFactory. Thank you for you're time @Khalid